# How to display default drupal search block in twig template

Tags: 8, theming, search

In twig_tweak module before version 2 (for Drupal 8) I could place the following code in my page twig template and it would work:

```
{{ drupal_block('exposedformsearch_contentpage_1') }}
```

This would display put the default site search box.

After upgrading to version 2, this doesn't work anymore and see the following message on the page:

```
This block is broken or missing. You may be missing content or you might need to enable the original module.
```

I tried using the command:

```
{{ drupal_block('search_form_block') }}
```

That displays the same error message.

Does anyone know what the the correct call is? I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere as to what the replacement call should be.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found the solution after playing around for a bit. The correct call now is:

```
{{ drupal_entity('block', 'exposedformsearch_contentpage_1') }}
```